# How to sum records grouped by month in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model **Dato**, which has a column called **Ingresos**.

I need to group **Ingresos** by month and sum all of the records in one month together for each month.

```
@datos = Dato.all
@datos_months = @datos.group_by { |t| t.date.beginning_of_month }
@datos_months_ingresos = @datos_months.sum(:ingresos)
```

This way I only get an array with all the columns instead of the ingresos sum by month.

Any ideas? Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very simple solution would be to use the gem [GroupDate](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate). This way you can do everything you need directly from your db instead of iterating over all the records in ruby:

`Dato.group_by_month(:created_at).sum(:ingresos)`

Here's where you can see the queries happening under the hood: https://github.com/ankane/groupdate/blob/master/lib/groupdate/relation_builder.rb.

Comment: Hi, thanks! It works, but I get [Mon, 01 Apr 2019, 108] in the view. How can I get only the value? 108? Thanks a lot!

Comment: That query will return a hash, so you can map over it and display it however you'd like depending on how you are templating your data.